# Heroku Cron To Go Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to run a script on Heroku. It's a simple scheduler that uses Cron To Go. No matter what I do, I keep getting

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/schedules.js'
```

Anyone have a suggestion? The schedules.js is in my root of the app.

Comment: What is the exact, complete command you're trying to run? Does it work if you run it once via `heroku run`?